# Prove Limit $5/(x+1)^3$ as $x \to -1^{-}$ is $-\infty$ epsilon delta proof

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I have to prove the following using the epsilon delta method

$$ \lim_{x \to \,-1^{-}} \, \frac{5}{(x+1)^3} = - \infty $$

So, using the language of quantifiers, I think, I have to prove the following

$$ \forall N < 0 \,\, \exists \delta >0 \,\, \forall x \in D \,\Big[ -1 - \delta < x < -1 \Bigr] \longrightarrow \Biggl[ \frac{5}{(x+1)^3}  < N \Biggr] $$

Now, playing with the consequent, I guessed the $\delta$ I needed here. So, following is my version of the proof.

Let $N < 0$ be arbitrary. Now choose

$$ \delta = \biggl( - \frac{5}{N} \biggr)^{1/3} $$

Since $N < 0$, we can see that $\delta > 0$. Now, let $x \in D$ be some arbitrary and then suppose that $ -1 - \delta < x < -1 $. After substituting for $\delta$, we have

$$ -1 - \biggl( - \frac{5}{N} \biggr)^{1/3} < x < -1 $$

From this, its clear that

$$ \biggl(  \frac{5}{N} \biggr)^{1/3} < x + 1  < 0$$

$$\therefore \frac{5}{N} < (x+1)^3 < 0$$

$$ \Rightarrow \,-\frac{5}{N} > -(x+1)^3 > 0$$

$$ \Rightarrow \,-\frac{N}{5} < -\frac{1}{(x+1)^3} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \,  \frac{5}{(x+1)^3}  < N$$

Since $x \in D$ and $N < 0$ are arbitrary to begin with, this proves the limit using epsilon delta method.

Is this good enough ?